# Convert JSON object to array?

Tags: json

I have this on my console on firebug,

```
[Object { fa_id="1167535",  f_id="1000",  loc_type="6",  more...}, Object { fa_id="1167535",  f_id="1000",  loc_type="6",  more...}]
```

it is data from the server side. Now, how would I convert this into array such that this data can be used on another file. I tried `JSON.parse` and `jQuery.parseJSON` but both did not work.

Comment: Your tags slightly confuse the matter. Do you want to get it into an array in JavaScript, or PHP?

Comment: again confusing .. JavaScript or php ?

Comment: You don't have JSON.  JSON is a *string representation* of data, that just so happens to share syntax with JavaScript.  You have an array of objects, what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: So why did you try `$.parseJSON`? That's a jQuery function. As others have said, you don't have valid JSON, so you're never going to get it to parse correctly...

Comment: Where is this data coming from?  Where do you want it to go?

Comment: @BenM, I'm sorry, I am quite confused here. I am new to this thing, so how would I exactly convert this into array of objects in PHP?

Comment: @CHiRiLo: You'd have to send it to PHP via AJAX.  Something like: `$.post('page.php', {data: yourObject});` then in PHP, you'd have `$_POST['data']` which would be an array of arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That isn't JSON it's a Javascript array of objects, not a string. My guess is that you've received this from a jQuery ajax call and you had the `dataType : 'json'` set so that jQuery has automatically parsed the JSON into this array.

To send it to a PHP script you can convert it back to JSON using:

```
var myString = JSON.stringify(data);
```

and then fire off an ajax call to the PHP script with that as the POST data:

```
var myString = JSON.stringify(data);
$.post('page.php', { data : myString }, function(){
    console.log( "sent" );
});
```

In PHP you can decode it using:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']); // <-- or whatever your post variable is named

foreach($data as $obj)
{
    echo $obj->fa_id;
}
```

Comment: actually you are correct. So how can I make this into an array of objects in PHP then?

Comment: @CHiRiLo see my edit. Basically you can convert it back to a string, then ajax it to PHP, then decode on the PHP side.

Comment: You could probably forgo the `JSON.stringify`, and just do `$.post('page.php', { data : data })`.  `$_POST['data']` would then just be a an array of arrays.

Comment: On javascript side you need to use 'JSON.stringify' and on server side something so that you can parse - like in ruby 'JSON.parse'

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get an php array use this

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

The string you provided is not valid JSON.

```
[Object { fa_id="1167535",  f_id="1000",  loc_type="6",  more...}, 
 Object { fa_id="1167535",  f_id="1000",  loc_type="6",  more...}]
```

In particular, the "`Object`" and "`more...`" strings cannot be interpreted by a JSON parser.

Assuming the object you are inspecting is a variable named `foo`:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(foo));
```

Should print a valid JSON representation of your object to the Javascript console.